# Why does the sort fail in the script but not in the one-liner?

Tags: perl

The following snippet works fine:

```
cat versions.txt | perl -Mversion -le'  
   chomp( @a = <> );  
   print for sort { $left = $a; $right = $b; $left =~ s!^\D+!!; $right =~ s!^\D+!!; version->parse($left) cmp version->parse($right) } @a;  
'
```

The following code does not, but I don't understand why. They seem to be effectively the same code.

```
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use version;  

chomp(my @versions = <>);  
@versions = sort { version->parse($a =~ s/^\D+//r) cmp version->parse($b =~ s/^D+//r) } @versions;   
print $_."\n" for @versions;
```

I get:

> Invalid version format (non-numeric data) at script line 7

Comment: What to `$a =~ s/^\D+//r` and `$b =~ s/^D+//r` print? I suspect something `parse()` doesn't like...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the non-working code, there's a simple typo.  You have:

```
@versions = sort { version->parse($a =~ s/^\D+//r) cmp version->parse($b =~ s/^D+//r) } @versions;
```

That might be better formatted as:

```
@versions = sort { version->parse($a =~ s/^\D+//r) cmp
                   version->parse($b =~ s/^D+//r) } @versions;
```

Split over two lines, the asymmetry (bug) is obvious.
You are missing the backslash before the second `D`:

```
@versions = sort { version->parse($a =~ s/^\D+//r) cmp
                   version->parse($b =~ s/^\D+//r) } @versions;
```

Comment: You were 1 minute faster than me :-)